# Помогите, пожалуйста, составить SQL запрос

Tags: sql, select

Есть таблица из трех колонок: id, number, date(смотрите скрин). Всего около 40к строк. В ней id и date всегда уникальны, а каждый number повторяться (повторов от 2 до 79).

Мне нужно посчитать у одинаковых number интервал времени в днях между каждой последующей date, т.е. только между соседними датами. Замечу, что чем больше id, тем date более поздняя.

Например: есть три строки с number=010501748932, date которых = 2017-06-23 11:52:28.237, 2017-06-26 11:30:13.357, 2016-05-06 12:43:41.813. Нужно вывести значения: 413(разница между 2016-05-06 12:43:41.813 и 2017-06-23 11:52:28.237) и 3(разница между 2017-06-23 11:52:28.237 и 2017-06-26 11:30:13.357).

В каком направлении мне двигаться?

[image: скрин]

Comment: Здесь не фриланс-биржа. Что именно вызывает у вас трудности, как вам помочь кроме выполнения всей работы за вас?

Comment: для каждой записи таблицы [tbl1] ищем в таблице [tbl2]  запись с таким же number , id которой меньше  [tbl1].id и максимальный , т.е. находим предыдущую запись, находим интервал в днях

Comment: Вам это принципиальное надо сделать на чистом sql? если да то решение можно нагуглить запросом  вида: как получить следующую строку от предыдущей, начиная с версии 2012 в sql вроде появились функции облегчающие решение данной задачи [lag](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) & [lead](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Bald спасибо за функции! очень помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Для MS SQL Server без оконных функций**

По оптимизации не уверен

> ```
> create table "Test"(
>   "id" int,
>   "number" varchar(15),
>   "date" date)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> insert into "Test" ("id","number","date") values
> ( 7387,'0101008461','2016-04-07 17:31:54.690'),
> (77109,'0101008461','2018-01-25 11:11:19.720'),
> (61009,'0105003182','2017-09-08 11:25:28.403'),
> (50859,'010501748932','2017-06-23 11:52:28.237'),
> (50998,'010501748932','2017-06-26 11:30:13.357'),
> ( 9978,'010501748932','2016-05-06 12:43:41.813');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select * from "Test"
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>    id | number       | date               
> ----: | :----------- | :------------------
>  7387 | 0101008461   | 07/04/2016 00:00:00
> 77109 | 0101008461   | 25/01/2018 00:00:00
> 61009 | 0105003182   | 08/09/2017 00:00:00
> 50859 | 010501748932 | 23/06/2017 00:00:00
> 50998 | 010501748932 | 26/06/2017 00:00:00
>  9978 | 010501748932 | 06/05/2016 00:00:00
> ```

> ```
> select
>   t01."id",
>   t01."number",
>   t01."date" "date_current",
>   t03."date" "date_previous",
>   datediff(day,t03."date",t01."date") "days"
> from "Test" t01
>    left join "Test" t03 
>    on 
>      t03."number" = t01."number"
>      and t03."date" = 
>     (
>      select
>        max(t02."date") "date"
>      from "Test" t02
>      where
>        t02."number" = t01."number"
>        and t02."date" < t01."date"
>     )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>    id | number       | date_current        | date_previous       | days
> ----: | :----------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | ---:
>  7387 | 0101008461   | 07/04/2016 00:00:00 | null                | null
> 77109 | 0101008461   | 25/01/2018 00:00:00 | 07/04/2016 00:00:00 |  658
> 61009 | 0105003182   | 08/09/2017 00:00:00 | null                | null
> 50859 | 010501748932 | 23/06/2017 00:00:00 | 06/05/2016 00:00:00 |  413
> 50998 | 010501748932 | 26/06/2017 00:00:00 | 23/06/2017 00:00:00 |    3
>  9978 | 010501748932 | 06/05/2016 00:00:00 | null                | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=15c83f1c62ef88a48b4d2d95d3d01a0d)*

Comment: спасибо! получилось

Answer (score 1):

> В каком направлении мне двигаться?

Решить задачу как её бы решал человек в отрыве от sql. Затем написать реализацию на sql.

Например, можно отсортировать весь список по `number, date`. Так одинаковые числа будут идти подряд и обязательно с наименьшим интервалом по дате.

Теперь можно завести в запросе [переменную](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) и сохранить в ней `number` и `date`. Для каждой строки выборки делать 2 действия: 1) сравнивать текущий `number` с тем, что уже в переменной; [совпал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) - считаем разницу между датами (текущей и той что уже в переменной); не совпал - выводим пустоту вместо разницы. 2) запоминаем в переменных текущий `number` и `date` для следующей строки выборки.